# Upload photo PHP/Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to upload a photo with Ajax and PHP, but return an error, and I don't know why:

> message: "move_uploaded_file(/site/uploads/users/user.png): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory"

RETURN (FILE):

```
C:\xampp\tmp\php2BAB.tmp
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#user-upload-photo").submit(function (){

        $("#user-upload-photo").ajaxSubmit({
            url: '/ajax/settings/upload',
            type: 'post',
            beforeSubmit: function(){
                $("#photo-loading").show();
                $("#photo-figure").hide();
            },
            success: function () {
                $("#photo-loading").hide();
                $("#photo-figure").show();
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```

This is the code that return the error:

Controller:

```
public function upload(){
    if(!empty($_FILES)):
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['user-photo-input']['tmp_name'])):
            $srcPath = $_FILES['user-photo-input']['tmp_name'];
            $trgPath = '/site/uploads/users/' . $_FILES['user-photo-input']['name'];

            if(move_uploaded_file($srcPath, $trgPath)):
                return response()->json(['succcess' => '1', 'photo' => $trgPath]);
            endif;

        endif;
    endif;
}
```

Comment: before i answer this question is /site/uploads/users/ folder available ?

Answer (score 5):

check first if the directory and all sub-roots  you are trying to upload to exists

```
if (!file_exists('path/to/directory')) {
    mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
}
```

if not, create it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel framework then you must use laravel predefined functions Try this code :-

```
public function upload(Request $request){
if($request->hasFile('user-photo-input')){
    if (Input::file('user-photo-input')->isValid()) {
        $file = Input::file('user-photo-inpu');
        $destination = 'site/uploads/users'.'/';
        $ext= $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $mainFilename = str_random(6).date('h-i-s');
        $file->move($destination, $mainFilename.".".$ext);
        echo "uploaded successfully";
    }
}
}
```

Make sure your folder must exists in public directory.
Hope it helps!

Comment: What's $request?

Comment: @ValterSousaCardoso it is parameter you need to define in function see my update answer .. it should be .. public function upload(Request $request){